# ReactDOM is not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, material-ui

I'm new to ReactJs and I've been meaning to make a website using React and Material-ui on a meteor framework. So far every thing seemed to go just fine but recently I've had a few problems.

This is my main.jsx (client side):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
var ReactDOM = require ('react-dom');

import {body_design} from '../imports/ui/ui_design/design_body.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
  <p>
    This is a test!
    <body_design/>
  </p>, 
  document.getElementById('main_body'));
});
```

As you can tell I'm trying to render body_design which is defined here (in design_body.jsx) :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';


import {Navigation_Bar} from './Template_design.jsx';

export const body_design = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Navigation_Bar/>
    </MuiThemeProvider>

);
```

And finally the Navigation_Bar is imported from here (in Template_design.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

// Needed for onTouchTap
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

export const Navigation_Bar = () => (
    <AppBar
        title = "Home"
        iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
    />
);
```

So the surprising thing here is, all my imports work correctly except for the react element in the ReactDOM.render call inside the main.jsx. When I launch the server in the browser "This is a test!" is printed out, but not the . Fun thing is the import{body_design} works perfectly...

Here is the main html for the placement :

```
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = 'main_body'>
    </div>
</body>
```

So the elements rendered by the main.jsx are correctly positionned. But for some reason the body_design leads nowhere. When I try to acess its definition path, it leads nowhere.

Help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: instead of `body_design` try `Body_design` (capital B).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mayank Shukla! That did the trick =)